# Microsoft Outlook isn't showing the correct email template

Tags: html, email, outlook, outlook-2010, outlook-2007

I'm making an email template , It works great on all email services except Microsoft Outlook 2007/2010..

Here's how its supposed to look

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yi1SP.png

Here's how it's looking on Outlook

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KST2h.jpg

Here's a look in the code itself

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Robot Coupe</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>&lt;%body%&gt;</p>

<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: 1px solid red;" width="600">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="line-height:0px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
            <p><span style="font-size:20px;"><span style="font-family:lucida sans unicode,lucida grande,sans-serif;"><strong><a href="http://www.robotcoupe.com.au" title="Robot Coupe"><img src="http://empaustralia.com.au/robot-coupe/logo.jpg" /></a></strong></span></span></p>

            <p><span style="font-family:lucida sans unicode,lucida grande,sans-serif;"><strong><a href="http://www.robotcoupe.com.au" title="Robot Cook"><img src="http://empaustralia.com.au/robot-coupe/robot-cook.jpg" /></a></strong></span> <img align="right" height="524px" src="http://empaustralia.com.au/robot-coupe/robot-cook.png" width="266px" /></p>

            <p><img src="http://empaustralia.com.au/robot-coupe/bullet.jpg" /><span style="font-family:comic sans ms,cursive;">Emulsify, grind, blend, chop, mix and<br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;knead to perfection.<br />
            <br />
            <img src="http://empaustralia.com.au/robot-coupe/bullet.jpg" />Hot, cold, sweet or savoury - it&rsquo;s all up<br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;to you!<br />
            <br />
            <img src="http://empaustralia.com.au/robot-coupe/bullet.jpg" />High speed and enviable cutting<br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;quality with the ability to heat<br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;up to 140&deg;C<br />
            <br />
            <img src="http://empaustralia.com.au/robot-coupe/bullet.jpg" />3.7 litre stainless-steel bowl</span></p>

            <p><span style="font-family:comic sans ms,cursive;font-size:13px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="707070">&ldquo;I don&#39;t see it as a machine, I see it as one of<br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;my chefs, with no days off. It&#39;s true, apart<br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;from doing our daily recipes in the machine,<br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;we&rsquo;re also constantly creating new techniques<br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;and recipes with the Robot Cook. It&#39;s so<br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;awesome I&rsquo;ll bring it to the next staff party, it&rsquo;s<br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;part of my kitchen team!&rdquo;</font></span><br />
            <a href="http://www.robotcoupe.com.au" title="Robot Coupe"><img align="left" alt="Bernard Chu" src="http://empaustralia.com.au/robot-coupe/Chu.jpg" style="padding:12px 0px 0px 0px" /></a><br />
            <span style="font-family:comic sans ms,cursive;font-size:13px;"><font color="#ed1c24"><strong>Bernard Chu</strong><br />
            LuxBite (South Yarra) and<br />
            T by LuxBite (Melbourne CBD)</font></span></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table bgcolor="#ed1c24" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" style="padding:10px 0px 10px 0px"><span style="font-family:comic sans ms,cursive;font-size:13px;"><font color="#ffffff">Call 02 9478 0300 to arrange a FREE demo in your kitchen.</font></span><br />
            <a href="mailto:orders@robotcoupe.com.au"><img src="http://empaustralia.com.au/robot-coupe/email.jpg" style="padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px" /></a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Completly wrong place to ask about MS Outlook

Answer (score 1):

the code is not created with HTML email in mind. I did a quick fix on the email. It is by no means comprehensive - not responsive or mobile friendly at all.  But this should now work 'betterish' in Outlook for you as well as in other email clients.

There is still a lot wrong with the code and layout - I would look up some design and development walkthroughs, etc and learn how HTML email is correctly formatted.

[SitePoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-code-html-email-newsletters/)

[CampaignMonitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/coding/)

[Litmus](https://litmus.com/blog/html-email-coding-101-infographic)

See code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Robot Coupe</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>&lt;%body%&gt;</p>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:1px; border-style:solid; border-color:red;" width="600">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="line-height:0px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
                <table align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                <tr>
                <td align="left"><a href="http://www.robotcoupe.com.au" title="Robot Coupe"><img src="http://empaustralia.com.au/robot-coupe/logo.jpg" /></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td align="left"><a href="http://www.robotcoupe.com.au" title="Robot Cook"><img src="http://empaustralia.com.au/robot-coupe/robot-cook.jpg" /></a></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <table align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                <tr>
                <td align="left">
                    <table align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                    <table align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top" style="vertical-align:top; padding-top:4px;"><img src="http://empaustralia.com.au/robot-coupe/bullet.jpg" /></td>
                    <td align="left" style="font-family:comic sans ms,cursive; padding-bottom:10px;">Emulsify, grind, blend, chop, mix and<br />
            knead to perfection.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top" style="vertical-align:top; padding-top:4px;"><img src="http://empaustralia.com.au/robot-coupe/bullet.jpg" /></td>
            <td align="left" style="font-family:comic sans ms,cursive; padding-bottom:10px;">Hot, cold, sweet or savoury - it&rsquo;s all up<br />
            to you!</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top" style="vertical-align:top; padding-top:4px;"><img src="http://empaustralia.com.au/robot-coupe/bullet.jpg" /></td>
            <td align="left" style="font-family:comic sans ms,cursive; padding-bottom:10px;">High speed and enviable cutting<br />
            quality with the ability to heat<br />
            up to 140&deg;C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top" style="vertical-align:top; padding-top:4px;"><img src="http://empaustralia.com.au/robot-coupe/bullet.jpg" /></td>
            <td align="left" style="font-family:comic sans ms,cursive; padding-bottom:20px;">3.7 litre stainless-steel bowl</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <table align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="font-family:comic sans ms,cursive; font-size:13px;padding-left:9px;"><font color="707070">&ldquo;I don&#39;t see it as a machine, I see it as one of<br />
            my chefs, with no days off. It&#39;s true, apart<br />
            from doing our daily recipes in the machine,<br />
            we&rsquo;re also constantly creating new techniques<br />
            and recipes with the Robot Cook. It&#39;s so<br />
            awesome I&rsquo;ll bring it to the next staff party, it&rsquo;s<br />
            part of my kitchen team!&rdquo;</font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td align="center">
             <table align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
             <tr>
            <td align="left" style="font-family:comic sans ms,cursive; font-size:13px;padding-left:9px; padding-top:10px;">
            <a href="http://www.robotcoupe.com.au" title="Robot Coupe"><img align="left" alt="Bernard Chu" src="http://empaustralia.com.au/robot-coupe/Chu.jpg" /></a></td>
            <td align="left" style="font-family:comic sans ms,cursive; font-size:13px;padding-left:9px; padding-top:10px;"><font color="#ed1c24"><strong>Bernard Chu</strong><br />
            LuxBite (South Yarra) and<br />
            T by LuxBite (Melbourne CBD)</font></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
                </td>
                <td align="right"><img align="right" height="524" src="http://empaustralia.com.au/robot-coupe/robot-cook.png" width="266" /></td>
                </tr>
                </table>


            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table bgcolor="#ed1c24" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" style="padding:10px 0px 10px 0px"><span style="font-family:comic sans ms,cursive;font-size:13px;"><font color="#ffffff">Call 02 9478 0300 to arrange a FREE demo in your kitchen.</font></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td align="center" style="padding:0 0px 10px 0px">
            <a href="mailto:orders@robotcoupe.com.au"><img src="http://empaustralia.com.au/robot-coupe/email.jpg" style="padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px" /></a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that Outlook uses Word (not IE) for rendering HTML markup of emails. All supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties you may find described in the following articles in MSDN:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Try to read articles and see what elements or properties are not supported in Word.